# Angular 6: Failed: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. (

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, bootstrap-4, karma-jasmine

I am testing my app using `npm test`

I am getting the following error :

```
Failed: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="nav-link active" [ERROR ->][routerLink]="['/movies']" routerLinkActive="active-link" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" c"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent.html@4:39
Can't bind to 'routerLinkActiveOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("l>
        <li><a class="nav-link active" [routerLink]="['/movies']" routerLinkActive="active-link" [ERROR ->][routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" class="fa fa-home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent.html@4:97
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("uterLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" class="fa fa-home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a [ERROR ->][routerLink]="['/movies']" class="fa fa-film"><span>Best Movies 200's</span></a></li>
        <li><a "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent.html@5:15
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("routerLink]="['/movies']" class="fa fa-film"><span>Best Movies 200's</span></a></li>
        <li><a [ERROR ->][routerLink]="['/theatre']" class="fa fa-television"><span>Movies in Theatre</span></a></li>
        "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent.html@6:15
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("ink]="['/theatre']" class="fa fa-television"><span>Movies in Theatre</span></a></li>
        <li><a [ERROR ->][routerLink]="['/tvshows']" class="fa fa-video-camera"><span>Tv Shows</span></a></li>
        <li><a "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent.html@7:15
'router-outlet' is not a known element:
1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("

<div class="container">
  [ERROR ->]<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/AppComponent.html@15:2
```

here is the html page am using , app html

```
<section>
  <div class="tabs tabs-style-fillup">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="nav-link active" [routerLink]="['/movies']" routerLinkActive="active-link" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" class="fa fa-home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/movies']" class="fa fa-film"><span>Best Movies 200's</span></a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/theatre']" class="fa fa-television"><span>Movies in Theatre</span></a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/tvshows']" class="fa fa-video-camera"><span>Tv Shows</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#section-fillup-5" class="fa fa-gear"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div><!-- /tabs -->
</section>

<div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

here is the main module , app module.ts

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
    import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { MoviesComponent } from './movies/movies.component';
    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing/app-routing.module';
    import { TheatreComponent } from './theatre/theatre.component';
    import { TvShowsComponent } from './tv-shows/tv-shows.component';
    import { DataFilterPipe } from './data-filter.pipe';
    import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    import {MatFormFieldModule, MatSortModule, MatInputModule, MatAutocompleteModule, MatBadgeModule, MatBottomSheetModule, MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material';
    import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';
    import { CdkTableModule } from '../..

/node_modules/@angular/cdk/table';
import { CdkTreeModule } from '../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/tree';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MoviesComponent,
    TheatreComponent,
    TvShowsComponent,
    DataFilterPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    CdkTreeModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatInputModule,
    HttpModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

here is my custom module for routing app routing module

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MoviesComponent } from '../movies/movies.component';
import { TheatreComponent } from '../theatre/theatre.component';
import { TvShowsComponent } from '../tv-shows/tv-shows.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'movies',
    component: MoviesComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'theatre',
    component: TheatreComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'tvshows',
    component: TvShowsComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'movies',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**

> UPDATE

**

Here is test spec .ts file

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));
  it(`should have as title 'app'`, async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('app');
  }));
  it('should render title in a h1 tag', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('h1').textContent).toContain('Welcome to movies-client!');
  }));
});
```

Note : I tried to add `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` to the app component.spec.ts stil the got the same error, tried different combination but nothing am I missing something in unit testing ? or what ?

**Question**

what is wrong with my codes?

Comment: have you import it in the test file ?

Comment: `I tried to add CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA to the app component.spec.ts stil the got the same error,` Where is your test spec file? You are adding it to `app.routing.module`. Show your test spec file.

Comment: alt read the question ain app module.ts is included, please check it,  Amit Chigadani this is not duplicate of what u have shared I am doing unit test in angukar 6 , he was doing just basic routing in angular 2 please !

Comment: @steve No I didnt am just learning this unit test so u know there is a lot to be learned hehe

Comment: Yes, this is not an exact duplicate. I have removed my comment. But you are probably not importing `RouterModule` in test spec. Check the answer. For testing you can use `RouterTestingModule`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should import `RouterTestingModule` in your test spec.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    .......
     imports: [
         RouterTestingModule,
         ......
     ],
     schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
     ......
})
```

Comment: In my app I dont see test.spec.ts I just have test.ts angular 6 many stuff changed though

Comment: So without writing your test spec you are try to run test cases. Strange. I would suggest you reading this tutorial https://angular.io/guide/testing

Comment: If you simply run `npm test` or `ng test`. It will obviously give you errors, because you have not configured your `app.component.spec`.  `test.ts` is not your spec, it is just the overall configuration of test environment.

Comment: I have updated the qn I have added app.component,spec.ts check it now

Comment: Great, Now import `RouterTestingModule` in your spec as shown. Also you should be importing other modules in your spec file whenever it is necessary. Please read the tutorial entirely and then start testing.

Comment: To be precise, you have to explicitly mention all the imports, declartions and providers for each test spec when it is required. Test spec wont automatically get them from `app.module` file.